# Two pictures of K-theory and Bott periodicity

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let me recall the definition of the Bott periodicity isomorphism in the context of $C^*$-algebras. We take a (class of) projection $p \in M_n(A^+)$ and map it to the class of $M_n(A)$ valued loop $f_p$ which is defined by 
$$f_p(z)=1_n+(z-1)p$$
(here $A^+$ is a unitization of $A$ (even if $A$ already has a unit) and $1_n$ is the identity matrix in $M_n(A)$).
Then the Bott isomorphism is defined as 
$$\beta: K_0(A) \ni [p]-[q] \mapsto [f_pf_q^*] \in K_1(SA).$$
In the classical (meaning: commutative) context Bott isomorphism is defined as multiplication by $[\gamma]-1$ where $\gamma$ is the tautological (complex) line bundle over compex projective space (which is the two sphere $S^2$).

> When the (unital) $C^*$-algebra is commutative then it is of the form $C(X)$ for some compact $X$. Then there is a natural isomorphism between $K^0(X)$ and $K_0(C(X))$. Is this isomorphism compatible with the Bott periodicity maps? If the answer is yes, why it is so?

Comment: The answer is yes.  In short, the Bott isomorphism as you defined it is the same thing as K-theory product with the $K_1$ class of the unitary valued function $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ on $S^1$.  There are isomorphisms $K_1(C(S^1)) \cong K_0(C(S^2)) \cong K^0(S^2)$ which respect K-theory products, and under this identification $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ corresponds to the traditional Bott class in topological K-theory.

Comment: Thank you, could you please provide more details? This question bothers me for a long time and I havent found the answer anywhere in the literature.

Comment: Dear Paul, as you can see, I offered the bounty for this question, if you could turn your comment into answer (providing some more details) I will be happy to accept it (forgive me putting such a comment but I;m not quite sure whether the person which wrote a comment under my post will get the information that bounty was offered for the question).